# how to retrieve session cookie from a node server running in openshift cloud

Tags: node.js, cordova, session, cookies, openshift

I have a node server.It uses express for session handling .

I have set `httpOnly: false`. I am trying to retrieve the session cookie from a cordova app running on localHost. when I run the node server on  localhost I can retrieve the cookie, but when I run the same node server on Openshift cloud ,I  can not retrieve the cookie . why is it so?
My express Session configuration is as follows:

```
{name:'session.id',
secret: 'xyz',
resave:false,
saveUninitialized:false,
cookie: { maxAge: null,httpOnly:false}}
```

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of googling I  found that cross domain session cookies reading is forbidden in new browsers.Thus there is no way I could read the cookies.But since I  have  control of the server in this case ,I can retrieve the cookies from the server by using normal GET request  to my server.